# How to remove the border frame a dialogframe

Tags: android

This question has been answered for a `Dialog` to my knowledg not for a `DialogFrame`.

I would like to remove the border shown in this picture.
Sorry no pictures allowed.

This is my code:

```
public class SettingDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public SettingDialogFragment() {
        // constructor
    }   

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ContextThemeWrapper context = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), 0);

        context.setTheme(R.style.dialog);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDlgBldr = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        alertDlgBldr.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_theme, null));

        return alertDlgBldr.create();
    }   
}
```

This is the **layout**:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        style="@style/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/dialog_theme_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/logo_color"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_text"
        style="@style/body"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/dialog_text"
        android:layout_below="@id/dialog_title"
        android:text="Demonstation how to use vector drawables to style a dialog box"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/logo_color" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/dialog_text"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/cats_dogs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the **style**

```
<style
    name="dialog">
    <!-- title encapsulating main part (backgroud) of custom alertdialog -->
    <item
        name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <!-- turn off any drawable used to draw a frame on the window -->
    <item
        name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_background</item>
        <!-- turn off any drawable used to draw a frame on the window -->
    <item
        name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <!-- float the window so it does not fill the screen -->
    <item
        name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <!-- remove the title bar we make our own-->
    <item
        name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <!-- remove the shadow from under the title bar -->
</style>
```

This the **drawable**

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid
        android:color="#00000000"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:color="#FFF000"
        android:width="3dp" />
</shape>
```

I think I tried every trick in the book now. Searched Stackoverflow for three days now, but most answers relate to `Dialog` not `DialogFragment`.
Please help me out

---

This code resolved the problem, finally!

```
public class SettingDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public SettingDialogFragment() {
        // this empty constructor without any parameter is required by Android
        // to in order to instantiate the fragment when it needs to do so.
    }   

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Light_Panel);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    }   

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_theme, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used

```
public class EventAgeGateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener {

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();       
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE);
        View view = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.the_dialog_layout, null);
        dialog.setContentView(view);  
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

Comment: but then dialogfragment is not dismissable on background touch. How to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

this line of code will help you

dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));

also check both links

1. [AlertDialog: How To Remove Black Borders Above and Below View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433764/alertdialog-how-to-remove-black-borders-above-and-below-view)
2. [DialogFragment remove black border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746766/dialogfragment-remove-black-border)

Comment: Tried this:  context.setTheme(R.style.DialogTheme);
  Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
  dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));But with the same resulting borders

Comment: Saw those post too, but no result.